# have background image zoomed inside transparent image or div

Tags: javascript, css

The question will be simple to understand once you see the image. I wish to replicate this image without resorting to image editing software, i am aware of the possibility to blur a background image, and was wondering if its possible to do the same with scaling. I'm open to using canvas/JavaScript as well

[image]

Comment: Yes, it's possible with lots of other elements, SVG, css clip-path and so on. Too broad for SO.

Comment: looks like, it's another with a separate background, not zoomed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an idea using `clip-path`:

```css
.box {
  height:300px;
  width:600px;
  background:var(--i) center/100% auto no-repeat; 
  position:relative;
}
.box:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  background:var(--i) center/200% auto no-repeat;
 clip-path: polygon(50% 20%, 70% 50%, 50% 80%, 30% 50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="box" style="--i:url(https://picsum.photos/2000/1000?image=1069)">

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks this will help me get started.

Comment: Oh, I like the `var()` CSS function, I didn't know it. Nice!

Answer (score 1):

You could create a div element with the same background image and zoom-in it.

So starting from an image:

```
img = document.getElementById(imgID);
```

you can create a "glass" div and put it on the image:

```
glass = document.createElement("DIV");
img.parentElement.insertBefore(glass, img);
```

then you use the same image as background:

```
glass.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + img.src + "')";
glass.style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat";
```

and zoom it as you need:

```
glass.style.backgroundSize = (img.width * zoom) + "px " + (img.height * zoom) + "px";
```

In order to create the shape you need, you can use this site [Clip maker](http://bennettfeely.com/clippy/)

Here a complete example:

```js
function magnify(imgID, zoom) {
  var img, glass, w, h, bw;
  img = document.getElementById(imgID);
  /*create magnifier glass:*/
  glass = document.createElement("DIV");
  glass.setAttribute("class", "img-magnifier-glass");
  /*insert magnifier glass:*/
  img.parentElement.insertBefore(glass, img);
  /*set background properties for the magnifier glass:*/
  glass.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + img.src + "')";
  glass.style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat";
  glass.style.backgroundSize = (img.width * zoom) + "px " + (img.height * zoom) + "px";
  bw = 3;
  w = glass.offsetWidth / 2;
  h = glass.offsetHeight / 2;
}

magnify("myimage", 3);
```

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box;}
.img-magnifier-container {
  position:relative;
}
.img-magnifier-glass {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 100px;
  top: 50px;
  left: 125px;
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 50%, 50% 100%, 0% 50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="img-magnifier-container">
  <img id="myimage" src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_fjords.jpg" width="300" height="200">
</div>
```

I hope it helps you, bye.